# Python (Key Error) when trying to write to an excel file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel

When I run this line of code:

```
def print_results():
    mfs_result = mfs_data[mfs_data['part_number'].isin(part_number_search)]
    fx_result = fx_data[fx_data['p_number'].isin(part_number_search)]
    fx_result_true = fx_result.query("loop_active == 'True'")
    return mfs_result, fx_result_true

full_results = print_results()


with pd.ExcelWriter(r"part_config_tester5.xlsx") as writer:
    full_results[0].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='MFS')
print("This works")
```

The pd.ExcelWriter works and will export the mfs_result dataframe to an excel file.

When I try to break up the results it will no longer read full_results dataframe.

```
def print_results():
    mfs_result = mfs_data[mfs_data['part_number'].isin(part_number_search)]
    return mfs_result

full_results = print_results()

def print_results2():
    fx_result = fx_data[fx_data['p_number'].isin(part_number_search)]
    fx_result_true = fx_result.query("loop_active == 'True'")
    return fx_result_true

fx_final_result = print_results2

with pd.ExcelWriter(r"part_config_tester6.xlsx") as writer:
    full_results[0].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='MFS')
    fx_final_result[1].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='FX')
print("This works")
```

I've doubled checked both dataframes to make sure that they are not empty. I've tried changing the path of that the file gets put in. I cannot seem to get a two sheet excel file to populate with each dataframe on the separate sheets

Comment: It would help a lot if you **actually said what the problem is**.  If this code is producing errors or unexpected output, then **show us** and explain **what you wanted instead**.

Comment: in your first example, you return **two items**, and so when you send to excel you need to use `full_results[0]`. But in the second example, these are split, and you are only returning **one item**, therefore not necessary to use `full_results[0]` anymore.

Comment: Welcome to SO, but you need to provide a [mre] including debugging details, such as a stack trace. ScottC's comment will solve your problem.